# Windows Phone 7: ListBox that lets the user add/remove items?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm building a wp7 Silverlight app. I need a list that is able to switch into "edit" and "not editing" mode. In "editing" mode, the list slides over, revealing icons that the user can tap to remove items from the list. At the bottom of the list is a "add" icon that lets users add new content.

Is there a standard control to use for this, or should I roll my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is implemented as part of the [August 2011 Mango updated toolkit](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2011/08/august2011phonetoolkit/).

Answer (score 2):

This control is a roll your own at the moment.. unless of course somebody decides to implement and publish the solution.